# TCPDF how do I create several pdf's without opening a browser

Tags: tcpdf

I need to create like 350 pdf's at once. Now the browser opens a window for each pdf. I takes longer to open all the 350 windows than to create the pdf's. How do I create and save the pdf's without opening a browser windows? (In my pdf I use Header, body and footer all with variables)

Now I do a loop on php_page_1 which opens the pdf create file.

```
  $sql = "SELECT id FROM shipping_id WHERE datum BETWEEN $date_range AND acc_id=$acc_id;";
  $STH = $dbo->prepare( $sql );
  $STH->execute();
  $contains_files = 0;
  $client_id='';    
  while ( $row = $STH->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
    $contains_files++;
    $link = "vb_print_1_no_screen.php?id=" . $row[ 'id' ] . "&nr=".$contains_files;

    echo '<script>window.open("https://' . $website_admin . $link . '");</script>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` to make the request to the URL instead of opening it directly in the browser or you can just `include` the file that generates the PDF. Try this code

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM shipping_id WHERE datum BETWEEN $date_range AND acc_id=$acc_id;";
$STH = $dbo->prepare( $sql );
$STH->execute();
$contains_files = 0;
$client_id='';    
while ( $row = $STH->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
    $contains_files++;
    $link = "vb_print_1_no_screen.php?id=" . $row[ 'id' ] . "&nr=".$contains_files;

    // echo '<script>window.open("https://' . $website_admin . $link . '");</script>';

    // method 1 using curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $website_admin . $link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // method 2 include pdf generator script
    $_GET['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_GET['nr'] = $contains_files;
    include "vb_print_1_no_screen.php";
}
```

Kindly make sure to use just one method.

Comment: None of the methods are working, methode 2 gives the first page but does not do the loop...

Comment: Can you share the code that generate the PDF as well?